# Как нормально отобразить кириллицу в xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, io

По тз есть определенный txt файл и его кодировку изменить невозможно но проблема в том что вместо текста идет отображение знаков вопроса.

```
var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(result.FullPath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
        {
            listView.ItemsSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Познакомьтесь с `File.ReadAllText` и `File.ReadAllLines`, кода станет меньше. К тому же есть и `...Async` варианты этих методов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Оказалось можно использовать Encoding.GetEncoding(1251); в связке с изменениями параметров В приложении как на картинке, надеюсь поможет кому-нибудь)

Comment: Пора бы уже файлы в кодировку UTF-8 сохранять, чтобы не таскать за собой устаревшие кодировки.